# Group hourly data by date

Tags: python, group-by

I got a dataframe which is a list with date and profit and loss by hour. I will need to add those hourly pnl up to come up with the total pnl each day.

here is the data I have:

```
                     date  pnl
0     2018-10-16 05:00:00  NaN
1     2018-10-16 06:00:00  0.0
2     2018-10-16 07:00:00 -0.0
3     2018-10-16 08:00:00 -0.0
4     2018-10-16 09:00:00  0.0
...                   ...  ...
43803 2023-10-15 08:00:00  0.0
43804 2023-10-15 09:00:00 -0.0
43805 2023-10-15 10:00:00 -0.0
43806 2023-10-15 11:00:00 -0.0
43807 2023-10-15 12:00:00 -0.0
```

I use a new column to store the daily pnl:

```
df['daily_pnl']= df.groupby(df.date.dt.day)['pnl'].sum()
```

which it only returns 33 numbers, is there anything wrong with my code? thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You're looking for [`dt.date`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html), not [`dt.day`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html). `dt.day` will just get you the nth day of the month (e.g. `13` for today), so currently you're grouping by each `nth` day.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** Adding each day's profit day by day and showing it in another column.

For example,

- If the daily profits go 1,2,3,4,...
- The total of each day is 1,3,6,10,...

**Code:**

```
df['daily_pnl'] = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['pnl'].cumsum()
```

**Sample Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2018-10-16 05:00:00', end='2023-10-15 12:00:00', freq='H')

data = {
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2018-10-16 05:00:00', end='2023-10-15 12:00:00', freq='H'),
    'pnl': list(range(1, len(date_rng) + 1))
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['daily_pnl'] = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.date)['pnl'].cumsum()

print(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT (adding total):**

You can get the total number of 'PNL':

```
total_pnl = df['pnl'].sum()
print("Total PNL:", total_pnl)
```

You can get the total number of 'Daily PNL':

```
total_daily_pnl = df['daily_pnl'].sum()
print("Total Daily PNL:", total_daily_pnl)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It does help a lot. How about I just want one total number for each day?  As I need to compare the dataset with another daily data, I would need one total number for each day.

Comment: I updated the post (EDIT part). The total of 'PNL' and the total of 'Daily_PNL' codes are added. Day-by-day addition was implemented before. For example, DAY5 (15) is the total of the days before and that day (1+2+3+4+5=15). These totals are calculated for each day.

Comment: Thank you!

Is it possible to create the dataset like below? I am looking for a list which shows the sum of hourly pnl for each day. But not the sum of the entire daily Pnl.

"
date                Daily Pnl
2018-10-16  (sum of the hourly PNL on Oct 16 2018)
2018-10-17 (sum of the hourly PNL on Oct 17 2018)
"

Appreciate your help!